# How can blocking of Installer .exe by Trend Micro Antivirus be prevented generated with Install4jc

Tags: install4j

The Installer .exe generated with Install4jc is blocked by Trend Micro Antivirus. How can this by prevented, without Trend Micro Antivirus configuration?

Comment: Trend Micro Antivirus detected the Installer .exe as Ransomeware!!

Answer (score 0):

You should submit a false positive report to the anti-virus software vendor, see

http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-report-malware-or-false-positives-multiple-antivirus-vendors.htm

Comment: In my view, this is a fundamental problem with the way the installer .exe is generated by the install4j product, that a generated installer .exe is detected as ransomware or malware by Micro Trend Antivirus. Therefore, I clearly see that you are as the manufacturer of software Install4j in the duty to solve that problem!

Comment: I have now fixed the problem by signing the Installer .exe and Launcher .exe, with a trusted keystore .p12 file by the install4j option "Code Signing => Sign Windows media files. Now it works fine!